# CSS shadow such that some div's look they are behind

Tags: html, css

Currently I have a HTML & CSS that results in a page like below

[image]

However, I want the shadows above B & C tabs so that it looks like they are behind.
Can anyone hele achieve this?

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(245, 165, 61);
  --border-rad: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80vh;
  margin: 5%;
}
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tab {
  width: 20%;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 2px 2px 0% 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: var(--border-rad);
  border-top-right-radius: var(--border-rad);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab:before,
.tab:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;

  height: 10px;
  width: 20px;

  bottom: 0;
}

.tab:before {
  left: -20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 var(--border-rad) 0;
  box-shadow: var(--border-rad) 0 0 0 #fff;
}

.tab:after {
  right: -20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 var(--border-rad);
  box-shadow: calc(var(--border-rad) * -1) 0 0 0 #fff;
}

.content {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 75vh;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 -3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab">A</span>
        <span class="tab">B</span>
        <span class="tab">C</span>
      </div>
      <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `position:relative` to .content

Comment: ... plus a z-index on the currently active tab (otherwise they will all be "behind".)

Comment: Combination of `position:relative` and `z-index` worked :-) Thanks a lot. If you want to put this as an answer, I will up-vote & accept it.

Comment: I wrote the same as an answer. If the guys don't post it as a response you could accept mine. It would be a big help in gaining some rp! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to temper with the z-index of the different elements. Remember you can only modify the z-index if the element itself has a position set (e.g. position: relative)

Below is a working example. Note that I have also added an "active" class to the currently active tab.

You would need to create JavaScript to make it full functional, but this is the starting point.

Good luck!

```css
body {
  background-color: rgb(245, 165, 61);
  --border-rad: 5px;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 80vh;
  margin: 5%;
}
.tabs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.tab {
  position: relative;
  width: 20%;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 2px 2px 0% 2px;
  border-top-left-radius: var(--border-rad);
  border-top-right-radius: var(--border-rad);
  position: relative;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}

.tab.active {
  z-index: 2;
}

.tab:before,
.tab:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;

  height: 10px;
  width: 20px;

  bottom: 0;
}

.tab:before {
  left: -20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 var(--border-rad) 0;
  box-shadow: var(--border-rad) 0 0 0 #fff;
}

.tab:after {
  right: -20px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 var(--border-rad);
  box-shadow: calc(var(--border-rad) * -1) 0 0 0 #fff;
}

.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 75vh;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 -3px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  border-radius: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
      <div class="tabs">
        <span class="tab active">A</span>
        <span class="tab">B</span>
        <span class="tab">C</span>
      </div>
      <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Even though it was working, I was not sure why. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

Just add these to your `content` and `tab` css classes:

```css
   .content {
      position: relative;
      z-index: 2;
    }

   .tab 
      z-index: 1;
    }
```

Edit: you need the `relative` positioning for `z-index` to work.

Answer (score 0):

You can always try the following css witch will give the box the black shadow and the border bottom you want.

```
box-shadow: rgb(0 0 0 / 25%) 0px 54px 55px, rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px -12px 30px, rgb(0 0 0 / 12%) 0px 4px 6px, rgb(0 0 0 / 17%) 0px 12px 13px, rgb(0 0 0 / 5%) 0px -3px 5px;
border-bottom: solid;
border-width: thin;
z-index: 50;
```